# Huge text or excel data Import FASTER into sql

Tags: sql-server, ssis, text-files, integration, fastercsv

I have a huge text file that has 1 million rows and each row there is  only 28 length number as text. 
I want to import them into sql server that has table corresponding column. So that a million data will be inserted to one column DB table.

I used SSIS, it's kind of slow. (1 million data will be inserted in 4.5 hours or more)  Are there any other ways to do that much faster ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use BCP utility for fast import . See official documentation here : [DOC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162802.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

As a result, I decided to sptling up the huge data into parts and run more SSIS at the same time through insert same table. There will be no lock in inserting. I hope 6 SSIS  finish this job nearly about an hour.

Thanks.

Comment: monitor your SQL Server and find the bottleneck. CPU? I/O? Network?